# Error printing 'bs4.element.NavigableString'

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am using Beautiful soup to scrap data from the Weather Underground website. I was able to get the exact data I want and assign it to a variable `dayTemp`. but when I try to print it using `print dayTemp`. I get the following error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#47>", line 1, in <module>
    print dayTemp
  File "C:\Python27\lib\idlelib\rpc.py", line 595, in __call__
    value = self.sockio.remotecall(self.oid, self.name, args, kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\idlelib\rpc.py", line 210, in remotecall
    seq = self.asynccall(oid, methodname, args, kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\idlelib\rpc.py", line 225, in asynccall
    self.putmessage((seq, request))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\idlelib\rpc.py", line 324, in putmessage
    s = pickle.dumps(message)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\copy_reg.py", line 74, in _reduce_ex
    getstate = self.__getstate__
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

I am using `span.string` to get the integer value out of the whole element.
The type of the variable `dayTemp` is `<class 'bs4.element.NavigableString'>`

Answer (score 1):

It seems idle fails to pickle `dayTemp`. You could try to convert it to Unicode string explicitely:

```
print unicode(dayTemp)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're just looking for `dayTemp.get_text()`  ([documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text))

Comment: NavigableString has no get_text() method. It is not surprising considering it is a subclass of `unicode` type