# BeautifulSoup recursion error calling tag.string

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

This is a really bizarre error that I can't seem to figure out.

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/'
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url))

print soup.title
```

This returns

```
<title>Beautiful Soup Documentation â€” Beautiful Soup 4.0.0 documentation</title>
```

as should be expected, but if I change it to "print soup.title.string" (which is supposed to return everything above minus the html tag) I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\MyProgram\Python\test.py", line 7, in <module>
    print soup.title.string
  File "C:\Python27\lib\idlelib\rpc.py", line 595, in __call__
    value = self.sockio.remotecall(self.oid, self.name, args, kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\idlelib\rpc.py", line 210, in remotecall
    seq = self.asynccall(oid, methodname, args, kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\idlelib\rpc.py", line 225, in asynccall
    self.putmessage((seq, request))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\idlelib\rpc.py", line 324, in putmessage
    s = pickle.dumps(message)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\copy_reg.py", line 74, in _reduce_ex
    getstate = self.__getstate__
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

I've looked around and can't find anybody else experiencing this error. Any advice?

Edit: So I've tried the same code on some other pages and it's worked better. google.com works for instance. This implies it's something about the construction of the pages.

Comment: Works for me in 4.0.1; what's your version number?

Comment: 4.1.3, the latest version they offer. I'll try going back a few versions and testing that out.

Comment: That's probably not it -- I just upgraded to 4.1.3 and it still works for me. :-/

Comment: Yeah, I tried both 4.1.0 and 4.0.1 and both gave the same error.

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13326821/error-printing-bs4-element-navigablestring) for someone else reporting the same.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is because it contains non_ASCII characters.
Modify your print statement to this

```
print soup.title.string.encode('ascii','ignore')
```